# Creating a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I've created custom post types in a theme before (actually on the exact theme I'm having trouble with now), and everything has gone relatively seamlessly. However, now I've run into an issue where a post type that I'm trying to create, with archive and content php files, is not working. More specifically, the slug is not working.

```
function sop_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'sop',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'SOPs' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'SOP' )
      ),
      'slug' => 'sop',
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-help',
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ]
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sop_posttype' );
```

Above is my registration for the post type. It is almost exactly the same as my previous post type, only with a different name.

My archive file is called archive-sop.php, and my content file is called content-sop.php.

I can't seem to see anything missing in my registration code, and the other post types are working correctly, but for some reason I'm still getting a 404 when I try to visit the archive page (http://url.com/sop/), even though I've added a test post.

Comment: Have you flushed your rewrites? Just go to "Settings" > "Premalinks" and hit Save.

Comment: Maybe check out the `rewrite` parameter of [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to flush the rewrite rules of WordPress. You can do it either by going to Permalink Settings and click save or by using [`flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

That's happens because WordPress doesn't know the URL-structure of your new custom post type. Read more here: [Custom Post Type and Permalink](http://wpengineer.com/2044/custom-post-type-and-permalink/)

Comment: Oh, duh. I remember having to do that previously. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code (unless there is more here) in your registration that will flush the permalinks.   Go to settings/peramlinks, and click save.  This should make the links work.

If you want code that will add to the cpt creation to do this automatically, let me know.